# Сделать ActionBar доступным на версиях Андроид ниже 3 (АПИ 10)?

Tags: actionbar, android, java

Всем добрый вечер!
Встал следующий вопрос: в процессе разработки приложения есть необходимость кастомизации `ActionBar`, а приложение должно работать на версиях АПИ выше 8.
Я знаю следующее из доккументации:

Для работы с `ActionBar` на более низких версиях необходимо использовать метод `getSupportActionBar` вместо `ActionBar`, а вместо `extends Activity` - `ActionBarActivity`, при этом необходимо подключить *android-support-library*. Так вот при использовании данного метода возникает ошибка:

> The method getSupportActionBar() is
> undefined for the type Main

Конечно можно использовать библиотеку **ActionBarSheerlock**, но этот вариант мне **не подходит**. Мое мнение, что скорее всего я неправильно подключаю библиотеку *Android support library*, и хотелось бы от вас подробнее узнать как это правильно сделать!

И еще вопрос связанный с этим.

Как быть в ситуации когда в одной активити необходимо задействовать `getFragmentManager` и `getActionBar`, так как по доккументации класс должен наследоваться и от `ActionBarActivity` и от `FragmentActivity`.

Буду рад любой помощи!

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Статья на харбре: [ActionBar на Android 2.1 с помощью Android Support Library](http://habrahabr.ru/post/187976/)

Вместо `getFragmentManager   - getSupportFragmentManager` и `getSupportActionBar` соответственно

Comment: Вы внимательно прочитали мой вопрос? Я об этом вообще то писал!

Comment: если в ide лаги попробуй студию, там это есть при создании проекта

Comment: В этой статье, которую Вы мне посоветовали говориться о библиотеке v7, а мой SDK manager показывает только v4

Comment: не совсем понял, в смысле не скачена ?

Comment: То есть в SDK manager нет этой библиотеки!

Comment: от меня все равно ускользает суть, в SDK manager просто раздел support library что на диске в sdk\extras\android\support ? должна быть папка v7

Comment: Да я знаю!!!)) Ее там нет!) Извините за !!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Вот детальная информация по получению и подключению необходимой support библиотеки.](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

И вместо **FragmentActivity** как раз нужно использовать **ActionBarActivity** с вызовами соответствующих support-методов вместо стандартных для более новых API:

**getFragmentManager -> getSupportFragmentManager**,  **getActionBar -> getSupportActionBar**, ...